# how do I avoid my placeholder to be in uppercase in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, css

So I added this css to my input box

```
text-transform: uppercase
```

So that it would automatically uppercase all my inputs. But my problem is when using Internet Explorer, it also automatically converts the placeholder in my input box as uppercase. I do not experience this in google chrome,firefox or safari. How can I avoid it not too automatically convert in IE9?

Comment: can you share the full code?

Comment: Why do you “uppercase” all your inputs? It only means that letters typed by the user are *shown* in uppercase but the actual data is in original case. So it is really misleading. Just let users type using any case and uppercase letters in *processing* the data if needed.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
/* Internet Explorer 10+ */
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-transform:none;
}
```

Comment: I got this to work in IE10 and IE11 but not in IE9. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

try Like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
    ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToUpper();
}
```